# Let $H$ and $K$ be normal subgroups of $G$, if $H \cap K = \{e\}$ prove that $hk = kh$ for all $h \in H, k \in K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I tried to use Lagrange's theorem's consequence which is $|HK| = |H||K|$ because $H \cap K = \{e\}$ but it doesnt bring me anywhere, i tried out the definition of normal subgroups as well but it is also lead me nowhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}$. Now $(hkh^{-1})k^{-1}\in K$ and $h(kh^{-1}k^{-1})\in H$ by normality of each, so $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H\cap K = \{e\}$, hence $hk = kh$.

Comment: oh my god you are damn good, may i learn how you tackle the question? I s it because $H \cap K = \{e\}$

Comment: @ilovewt Showing $hk=kh$ is usually hard, but showing $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}=e$ is usually easier, so I tried it. :)